# Выполнить SELECT попутно выполняя UPDATE

Tags: sql, sqlite

Есть таблица типа такой:

`` create table `Notifications` ( `From` text, `To` text, `State` integer ) ; ``

При выборке из таблицы необходимо изменить поле `State`. В моём случае я сначала делаю `SELECT` с `LIMIT 1`, чтоб проверить наличие записей, затем делаю `UPDATE`, чтоб выставить везде нужный `State` и потом уже вызываю ещё раз `SELECT`, чтоб выбрать данные из таблицы и начать с ними работать.

Есть варианты как изменить содержимое `State` при выборке данных из  таблицы?

Comment: Никак. Только не понятно, зачем второй селект. Выбрали данные, если все гуд, отправили апдейт и продолжайте работать с данными, которые уже и так у вас.

Comment: Судя по документации (сам не проверял) sqlite поддерживает конструкцию returning, но только для операции insert, но не для update. Если изобразить ваш update как insert с `on conflict` (что бы он в апдейт превратился, запись то у вас есть) то может и прокатить https://www.sqlite.org/lang_returning.html

Comment: Второй SELECT для оптимизации. В моём случае новые данные в таблице появляются не так часто, поэтому если сразу делать UPDATE для выставления флага и затем SELECT для выборки, то в большинстве случаев эти 2 запроса будут лишней тратой ресурсов. Поэтому я делаю первый SELECT просто для проверки наличия данных.

Comment: Про returning не до конца понял. Записей в таблице может быть несколько. С помощью UPDATE я помечаю их все, что они приняты в обработку. Как в таком случае заменить UPDATE на INSERT не могу сообразить.

Comment: Подозреваю, что как раз первый запрос select это лишняя трата ресурсов. Особенно когда update возвращает все что он изменил. Если ничего не вернул значит ничего и не было, а по таблице для поиска записей которые менять он пройдет с той же скоростью что и select

Comment: Я извиняюсь. UPDATE что-то возвращает разве?

Comment: даже если нет returning то по крайней мере он возвращает количество измененных записей и если оно не 0 то можно читать. А раз у вас returning заработал, то у вас вообще все отлично

Comment: Про количество обработанных записей не знал. Благодарю. Returning заработал, да. Оказывается, он  там для delete, insert и update работает.

Answer (score 1):

Пинок в сторону `RETURNING` был верным. sqlite поддерживает его для `UPDATE` тоже, таким образом запрос

`` update `Notifications` set `State` = 1 returning `From`, `To` ; ``

Делает то, что мне нужно.